# AJAX to PHP to mySQL debugging

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, debugging

I am having trouble my change password script for my website. I am using an AJAX connection to my php. My database connection is solid, and it is sending the correct variables (according to firebug), but they get lost in translation I guess. I am having trouble printing out error reports because my theme is covering them all up. I realize the code isn't very secure, and I intend on changing that. But for right now, I just need some help getting this code to work. I have been working on it for the past two days now, and I can't seem to find the niche.

Here is my login page with code included.

```
    <?php

    include_once("php_includes/check_login_status.php");
    ob_start();
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_error', 'on');
    $isOwner = "no";
    if($user_ok == true){
        $isOwner = "yes";
        $u = $_SESSION['username'];
    } else {
        header("location: http://www.ibnwmo.com");
    }
?>
<?php
// AJAX CALLS THIS CODE TO EXECUTE
if(isset($_POST['u'])) {
    include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
    $username = '';
    $oldpasshash = '';
    $newpasshash = '';
    $username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['u']);
    var_dump($username);
    $oldpasshash = md5($_POST["cp"]);
    $newpasshash = md5($_POST["cnp"]);
    $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $db_id = $row["0"];
    $db_username = $row["1"];
    $db_password = $row["2"];
    $dump = var_dump($cnp);
    $dump2 = var_dump($cp);
    if($db_password != $oldpasshash){
        echo "no_exist";
        exit();
    } else {
        $sql = "UPDATE users SET password='$newpasshash', WHERE username='$db_username' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    }
    $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username='$db_username' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $db_newpass = $row[3];
    if($db_newpass == $newpasshash) {
    echo "success";
    exit();
    } else {
        echo "pass_failed";
        exit();
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Forgot Password</title>
<link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mainstyle.css">
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
<script>
function changepass() {
var u = _("username").value;

var cp = _("currentPass").value;

var np = _("newPass").value;

var cnp = _("confirmNewPass").value;

if(np != cnp) {
    _("status").innerHTML = "The passwords given do not match!";
    } else if (cp === "" || np === "" || cnp === "") {
        _("status").innerHTML = "Please fill out all of the fields.";
    } else {
        _("changepassbtn").style.display = "none";
        _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "change_password.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) === true) {
        var response = ajax.responseText;

      if(response == "success") {
          _("status").innerHTML = '<h3>Your password has been changed!</p>';
        } else if (response == "no_exist") {
          _("status").innerHTML = "Sorry, your current password was entered incorrectly.";
          _("changepassbtn").style.display = "initial";
        } else if (response == "pass_failed") {
            _("status").innerHTML = "Sorry, the password change failed.";
            _("changepassbtn").style.display = "initial";
        } else {
            _("status").innerHTML = "An unknown error occurred";
            _("changepassbtn").style.display = "initial";
        }
      }
    };
    ajax.send("u="+u+"&cp="+cp+"&np="+np+"&cnp"+cnp);
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the front end is submitting the values you expect, you can continue debugging the php code with logging statements, i.e. in change_password.php:

`error_log(date('YmdHis').": ".print_r($_REQUEST,true)."\n", 3, '/tmp/change_password.log');`

Comment: The log will show up in /tmp/change_password.log, see [the error_log php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php).